# Git initial Setup on server Fatal error: Out of memory, realloc failed

Tags: git, bash, github, ssh

There are existing files in the server. Wordpress website to be exact. I want to setup git and push those files to github. Problem is that i always have an error and i can't get through. Here are the steps I did to setup git on our server:

```
1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "initial setup"
```

then a problem occurred with the following errors:

```
fatal: Out of memory, realloc failed
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
```

I tried increasing the `packedGitLimit`, `packSizeLimit`, `windowMemory` etc. But still no good. Any idea or insights on how to fix this? Thanks

Update: Here's the cmd output to the problem

https://www.screencast.com/t/nIStE8Ft

Comment: It looks like you either have a lot of large files (large ones?) and they do not fit into the memory. Or there is some recursive symlinks? It is impossible to say without more information.

Comment: I'm using this cmd to find and ignore large files `find . -size +50M | cat >> .gitignore` but still the problem occurs. What do you mean by symlinks? That is the only info i can provide cause me neither has no idea what went wrong

Answer (score 3):

Was able to find the answer on my own. This command simply did the trick:

`git config --global core.preloadIndex false`

After running that command, issues above were fixed.

Comment: this command fixed the issue for me, but I had the same issue but it was due to less ram allocation due to which preloadIndex was failing

Answer (score 0):

Above solution didn't work for me. I was having this error on checking out a branch. I had to delete the "**.git/hooks/post-checkout**" file. And it worked form me. Just mentioned if anyone else encounter with same kind of issue.